# Can't get my Persona to appear

Tags: resourceobject, llm

I am trying to use the new LLM functionality in a Mathematica 13.3 installation. I already got the connection to OpenAI working and can use a chat-driven notebook.

My intention at the moment is exploratory chat about themes mostly not related to mathematics, code writing and so on, but on history, philosophy, literature etc. and story telling.

I created for ChatGPT in the OpenAI web interface a Persona via the "Custom instructions" that I called David. Now I tried to transfer it and produced a Notebook David.nb in the special format ("Prompt Resource Definition Notebook"). I created this notebook initially with a certain command in a usual notebook, unfortunately I do not know at the moment what exactly this command was.

But this is not the main problem. By taking ELI5 as a model I filled this notebook (David.nb) with the text I had used formerly with OpenAI "Custom instructions". The notebook passed the self-test and I clicked on "Deploy > Locally". There was a folder created under

```
juergen@regulus:~/mathematica/llms$ ls ~/.Wolfram/Objects/DeployedResources/Prompt/David/
object.wl  put.wl
```

Now I wanted to "install" this Persona in a chat-enabled notebook by clicking on the lead-in-icon as described and then on "Add & Manage Personas". As I did not submit to the internet repository of Prompts but deployed only locally, it seems necessary to give the URL here. I tried several versions but got errors every time.

It seems there could be two problems:

1. The URL is wrong (but the Persona was correctly generated and locally deployed)
2. The URL was ok but the Persona was (despite the self-check showed no errors and also the Deploy command in David.nb gave no error) not generated correctly.

Could anyone acquainted with this process give me some guidance here? (Of course I googled a lot, tried to find the answer in the local Mathematica Help System and even asked in an GPT Chat in Mathematica itself, but nothing led me to success).

ADDENDUM: I now managed to do it via my private cloud through a http-url. But I am still interested in a purely local workflow.